# Same app is deployed normally in shinyapps.io in one machine and is not in the other

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have the shiny app below which I deploy on 2 different shinyapps.io accounts on 2 different machines. The app is below: In the first machine it works fine and in the second it breaks down. Can you find some difference between the logs that explains that?

```
library(shiny)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(tidyverse)
# probably don't need all of these:
library(DiagrammeRsvg)
library(svglite)
library(svgPanZoom)
library(rsvg)
library(V8)# only for svg export but also does not work
library(xml2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("save_svg","Save"),
  grVizOutput("grr",width = "100%",height = "90vh")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  reactives <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    reactives$graph <- render_graph(create_graph() %>%
                                      add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
                                      add_edge(
                                        from = 1,
                                        to = 2,
                                        edge_data = edge_data(
                                          value = 4.3)))
  })
  output$grr <-
    renderGrViz(reactives$graph
    )
  output$save_svg <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function() {
      "test.svg"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      reactives$graph %>%
        export_svg() %>%
        read_xml() %>%
        write_xml(file)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the first machine it is deployed and works fine and here are its logs:
[image]

In the second machine it breaks down and here are its logs as well.

```
2021-12-14T19:49:26.837108+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Running on host: 77ef44bdd920    
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843541+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Server version: 2021.11.0    
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843555+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: LANG: C.UTF-8
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843563+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: R version: 3.6.0
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843563+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: httpuv version: 1.5.2
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843563+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: shiny version: 1.7.1
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843564+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: rmarkdown version: 2.11.2
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843571+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: knitr version: 1.34
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843609+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: jsonlite version: 1.7.2
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843622+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843623+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: htmltools version: 0.5.2
2021-12-14T19:49:26.843944+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
2021-12-14T19:49:27.106315+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2021-12-14T19:49:27.110081+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: 
2021-12-14T19:49:27.110082+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Starting R with process ID: '26'
2021-12-14T19:49:27.110511+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Shiny application starting ...
2021-12-14T19:49:28.317822+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
2021-12-14T19:49:28.322136+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✔ ggplot2 3.3.3     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
2021-12-14T19:49:28.322137+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✔ tibble  3.1.1     ✔ dplyr   1.0.5
2021-12-14T19:49:28.322138+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✔ readr   1.4.0     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
2021-12-14T19:49:28.322138+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✔ tidyr   1.1.3     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
2021-12-14T19:49:28.422481+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
2021-12-14T19:49:28.422485+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
2021-12-14T19:49:28.422485+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
2021-12-14T19:49:28.881525+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Using V8 engine 6.8.275.32-node.55
2021-12-14T19:49:28.955121+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: 
2021-12-14T19:49:28.955123+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36033
2021-12-14T19:49:40.754912+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Exception thrown during bootstrapping
2021-12-14T19:49:40.754937+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: 
2021-12-14T19:49:40.754938+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  *** caught segfault ***
2021-12-14T19:49:40.754944+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758589+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: 
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758589+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: Traceback:
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758590+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  1: make_context(private$console)
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758590+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  2: reset()
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758716+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  3: (function() {    eval <- function(src) {        get_str_output(context_eval(join(src), private$context))    }    validate <- function(src) {        context_validate(join(src), private$context)    }    call <- function(fun, ..., auto_unbox = TRUE) {        stopifnot(is.character(fun))        stopifnot(this$validate(c("fun=", fun)))        jsargs <- list(...)        if (!is.null(names(jsargs))) {            stop("Named arguments are not supported in JavaScript.")        }        jsargs <- vapply(jsargs, function(x) {            if (is.atomic(x) && inherits(x, "JS_EVAL")) {                as.character(x)            }            else {                toJSON(x, auto_unbox = auto_unbox)            }        }, character(1))        jsargs <- paste(jsargs, collapse = ",")        src <- paste0("JSON.stringify((", fun, ")(", jsargs,             "));")        out <- this$eval(src)        get_json_output(out)    }    source <- function(file) {        if (is.character(file) && length(file) == 1 && grepl("^https?://",             file)) {            file <- curl(file, open = "r")            on.exit(close(file))        }        this$eval(readLines(file, encoding = "UTF-8", warn = FALSE))    }    get <- function(name, ...) {        stopifnot(is.character(name))        get_json_output(this$eval(c("JSON.stringify(", name,             ")")), ...)    }    assign <- function(name, value, auto_unbox = TRUE, ...) {        stopifnot(is.character(name))        obj <- if (inherits(value, "JS_EVAL")) {            invisible(this$eval(paste("var", name, "=", value)))        }        else {            invisible(this$eval(paste("var", name, "=", toJSON(value,                 auto_unbox = auto_unbox, ...))))        }    }    reset <- function() {        private$context <- make_context(private$console)        private$created <- Sys.time()        if (length(global)) {            context_eval(paste("var", global, "= this;", collapse = "\n"),                 private$context)        }        if (isTRUE(typed_arrays)) {            context_enable_typed_arrays(private$context)        }        invisible()    }    console <- function() {        this$eval("")        message("This is V8 version ", version(), ". Press ESC or CTRL+C to exit.")        on.exit(message("Exiting V8 console."))        buffer <- character()        has_history <- !inherits(try(savehistory(tempfile()),             silent = T), "try-error")        if (has_history) {            savehistory()            on.exit(loadhistory(), add = TRUE)            histfile <- ".V8history"            if (file.exists(histfile)) {                loadhistory(histfile)            }            else {                file.create(histfile)            }        }        rc.options(custom.completer = function(env) {            env$comps <- tab_complete(this, env$token)        })        on.exit({            rc.options(custom.completer = NULL)        }, add = TRUE)        repeat {            prompt <- ifelse(length(buffer), "  ", "~ ")            if (nchar(line <- readline(prompt))) {                buffer <- c(buffer, line)            }            if (identical(buffer, "exit"))                 break            if (length(buffer) && (this$validate(buffer) || !nchar(line))) {                if (has_history) {                  write(buffer, histfile, append = TRUE)                  loadhistory(histfile)                }                tryCatch(cat(undefined_to_null(this$eval(buffer))),                   error = function(e) {                    message(e$message)                  })                buffer <- character()            }        }    }    reset()    lockEnvironment(environment(), TRUE)    structure(environment(), class = c("V8", "environment"))})()
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758722+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  4: new_context("window")
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758723+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  5: export_svg(.)
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758732+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  6: read_xml(.)
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758733+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  7: write_xml(., file)
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758739+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  8: reactives$graph %>% export_svg() %>% read_xml() %>% write_xml(file)
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758739+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:  9: download$func(tmpdata)
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758746+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: 10: ..stacktraceon..(download$func(tmpdata))
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758757+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: 12: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758761+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: 13: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
2021-12-14T19:49:40.758797+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: 14: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        sm <- strsplit(conditionMessage(e), "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && isTRUE(getOption("show.error.messages"))) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
```

Comment: To me the glaring differences (other than the stack/dump errors) are that the error-laden app is running on R-3.6.0 (vs R-4.1.1) with several older packages (`httpuv`, `knitr`, and most of the tidyverse). I suggest upgrading both R and your packages to the same versions and try again.

Comment: FYI, shiny logs can occasionally be dumped out-of-order; I edited the question to place the log entries in order in order to make it easier to read the traceback and such. If that's a problem, you can always revert my change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099597/update-a-dataset-after-putting-a-new-value-in-the-dtdatatable could you take a look at this?