# Update a dataset after putting a new value in the dt::datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a dataframe with a column full of `NAs` and I want to be able to fill those `NAs` but the search filter of the `landman` column still remains deactivated. Is there a way to update the dataset I use every time I put a value in the `landman` column and use a submitButton to update it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
d <- structure(list(owner = c(
  "7 MILL IRON RANCH LLC", "7/S LAND & CATTLE COMPANY LLC",
  "AHL/KENNETH L(TRUSTEE & JOHN E AHL ETAL"
), acres = c(
  1900.6207117,
  654.7908393, 641.3866548
), n = c(5L, 2L, 1L), landman = c(
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_, NA_character_
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))

#d$landman <- letters[1:3]

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("sel","select",choices = d$owner,multiple=T,selected = d$owner[1])
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    dataTableOutput("TABLE"),
  )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$TABLE_cell_edit, {
    d <<- editData(d, input$TABLE_cell_edit, 'TABLE')
  })
  
  output$TABLE <- renderDataTable({
    input$TABLE_cell_edit
    
    d<-subset(d,d$owner%in%input$sel)
    datatable(d,
              filter = "top", editable = "cell", class = "hover cell-border stripe",
              caption = "Owners wit more than 500 aggregated accrs",
              extensions = "Buttons",
              options = list(
                dom = "Bfrtip",
                buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel")
              )
    )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get it the filter for the datatable columns gets deactivated when a column contains only one value, i.e. that's not specific to `NA`s. The same occurs if you replace the `NA`s by empty strings or e.g. an `a`. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything on this behavior in the documentation.

However, to activate the filter after you edited a cell you could follow the [example app](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/) referenced in Section 2.4 of the [docs](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html). Following the example you could add an `observeEvent` to update your dataset `d` to take account of the editing. Additionally to ensure that the `datatable` gets updated I made `renderDataTable` reactive on `input$TABLE_cell_edit`. After doing so that datatable gets updated after an edit and the filter gets activated automatically:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
d <- structure(list(owner = c(
  "7 MILL IRON RANCH LLC", "7/S LAND & CATTLE COMPANY LLC",
  "AHL/KENNETH L(TRUSTEE & JOHN E AHL ETAL"
), acres = c(
  1900.6207117,
  654.7908393, 641.3866548
), n = c(5L, 2L, 1L), landman = c(
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_, NA_character_
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))

#d$landman <- letters[1:3]

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    dataTableOutput("TABLE"),
  )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$TABLE_cell_edit, {
    d <<- editData(d, input$TABLE_cell_edit, 'TABLE')
  })
  
  output$TABLE <- renderDataTable({
    input$TABLE_cell_edit
    
    datatable(d,
      filter = "top", editable = "cell", class = "hover cell-border stripe",
      caption = "Owners wit more than 500 aggregated accrs",
      extensions = "Buttons",
      options = list(
        dom = "Bfrtip",
        buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel")
      )
    )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: hi thanks what if the data is reactive with shiny widget like my edit?

Comment: Works fine. (: As I said. If a column contains only one value the filter is deactivated. I would guess that's because if there is only one value than a filter does not make any sense.

Comment: can u check my edit?it does not work now

Comment: Already checked your edit. When I run your edited code the datatable shows only one row. Now, if I edit the cell for this row in landman column there is only one unique value. Hence, the filter is deactivated. Only when the column contains different values the filter gets activated.